# Can TFS be accessed from QNX?

Tags: tfs, qnx

Specifically, I need to check in/out files from a QNX box, but I don't see any evidence online that this is supported.

Has anyone had luck doing this?

Comment: Have never tried it. The Java bases Cross Platform Command Line might work. If that works then maybe Team Explorer Everywhere might work as well (it requires an eclipse based IDE). http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661

Comment: I know this is an old question but don't see an answer. download link for plugin: [Team Explorer Everywhere for Team Foundation Server ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661) Just installed it on Momentic IDE. Don't know what IDE you're using but it works fine for this one.